# Uncaught type error while uploading the file jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

Hello i am using a from to upload the song on my wordpress website.I use a form where a person can upload one/multiple song files to the server.

### My form is :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="songs[]" id="songs" multiple="multiple">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I want to get the file name after selecting file using the form(before pressing the submit).

### I used this code:

```
var song_file = jQuery('#songs')[0].files[0]
  if(song_file){
  alert(song_file.name);
}
```

### AND

```
var filename = jQuery('#songs').prop("files")[0]['name'];
alert(filename);
```

But there is a console error : 
   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

How i can solve this??

And how i can get the full URL using the file ??

For example : one url is : `http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mpthreetest.mp3`

Another usrl is : `http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/mpthreetest.mp3`

So i need only the date to be fixed on url and i will get file name from the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking at it on pageload, when it's still empty. You should look at the files on any change events to the input field, like this:

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input:file").change(function(event) {
    var song_file = $('#songs')[0].files[0];
    if (song_file) {
      alert(song_file.name);
    }
  });
})
```

**Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en5rgbvg/1/)**

Comment: Hello thanks,It works,But it shows when i press submit button.But i need when user selects the file before submitting

Comment: Updated answer to file change instead of submit

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

It's probably referring to `jQuery('#songs').prop("files")[0]['name']`.

The following is an empty jQuery object:

```
jQuery('#songs').prop("files")
```

To answer your question *"How i can solve this"*, start by looking at why your selector `jQuery('#songs').prop("files")` isn't matching anything.

**EDIT**

Inspect the element with ID `songs`, can you see a `files` property? Is it an array? Does it contain anything? Does the first element contain a name property?

Your error could also come from the `alert` line: `alert(song_file.name);`

Just check the console, it'll point you to the right line.

Comment: Hello i am using wordpress.If i use `$` then comes `$ is not a function`

Comment: it is `<input type="file" name="songs[]" id="songs" multiple="multiple">`

Comment: If i use `var filename = jQuery('#songs').prop("files")[0]` then an alert comes `undefined`

Comment: But that comes after page load.but i need to appear that after selecting the file

Comment: You need to make the file check on submit, like in the other answer.